# Attaching workflows: Customize task list name

Tags: workflow, tasks, task-list

When attaching the workflow to a list, how do you customize the task list name? I did it before but can't for the life of me remember how to do it anymore.[image]

Answer (score 1):

The drop down shows all available tasks lists. If your site only has a Workflow Tasks, then that is what shows up. You'd just need to create a new task list with your desired name, and it should be available in that drop down.

*Answer update: You can just select new task list and after it's created, you can change the task list name.

Comment: hmm... I just tried it and it didn't show up. Do I need to set the task list to some specific setting?

Comment: Is there an option for a new task list in the drop down? Admittedly, I didn't try this in 2013, this is just the way it worked in 2007 and 2010.

Comment: i did, but it didn't show up in the drop down for some strange reason. But, you can just as easily select a new task list and then rename that list after it's created. Thanks a bundle!